Is this a correct way to initialize all the bit fields in a struct?
I'm packing bools together in a c++ struct and I want to initialize them all to zero when constructed.
Is this a correct/safe way to do it?
I think it is but I'm not 100% sure and I'd like the lawyers to weigh in...
struct packed_flags {
  // All the flags (there's less than 16 of them)
  bool f1: 1;
  bool f2: 1;
  bool f3: 1;
  bool f4: 1;
  // ...

  // Pad the struct to a 16-bit size
  uint16_t: 0;

  // Constructor to initialize them all to 'false'
  packed_flags() {
    *(uint16_t*)(this) = 0;
  }
} flags;


Bitfields probably do not do what you expect them to do. They do NOT control memory layout (that's compiler specific/implementation defined). The only guarantee you have is that you get an integer that behaves as it it had n bits. So that means that in practice you will have to manage individual bits (masking/and/or/shift etc). Or have a look at std::bitset

Also using the "C" style cast (uint16_t) is just an accident waiting to happen. I am pretty sure you saw this kind of thing in "C" but it isn't going to work in C++

A union makes the code a lot more messy, I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Simplest is to avoid bit fields entirely (due to implementation defined layout).  Use one or more fixed width unsigned integer types and add get/set methods with masking and shifting.

Also be aware of Bit-field - "...The following properties of bit-fields are implementation-defined:..." ... "...Everything about the actual allocation details of bit-fields within the class object...."

Is this a correct/safe way to do it? No.

*(uint16_t*)(this) = 0; is an aliasing violation and therefore undefined behavior. *this is not of type uint16_t nor does any object of type uint16_t exist that is pointer-interconvertible with *this.
The correct way to force the default constructor to zero all members is to not write any default constructor at all, instead relying on the implicitly-defined one, and explicitly specifying default member initializers instead (since C++20):
struct packed_flags {
  // All the flags (there's less than 16 of them)
  bool f1: 1 = 0;
  bool f2: 1 = 0;
  bool f3: 1 = 0;
  bool f4: 1 = 0;
  // ...

  // Pad the struct to a 16-bit size
  uint16_t: 0 = 0;
} flags;

Before C++20 you can simply write a default constructor that assigns 0 to each bit-field manually.
Or, even without these default initializers you can use initialization by () or {}, to force zero-initialization (since C++03/C++11):
struct packed_flags {
  // All the flags (there's less than 16 of them)
  bool f1: 1;
  bool f2: 1;
  bool f3: 1;
  bool f4: 1;
  // ...

  // Pad the struct to a 16-bit size
  uint16_t: 0;
} flags = {};

Also, uint16_t: 0; is not guaranteed to pad the structure as you want it. It only specifies that the next bit-field shall begin at a new bit-field allocation unit boundary, but there is no following bit-field.
If you want to force the structure to have a specific alignment (implying that its size is an integer multiple of that alignment), then you should use alignas instead:
struct alignas(2) packed_flags {
  // All the flags (there's less than 16 of them)
  bool f1: 1;
  bool f2: 1;
  bool f3: 1;
  bool f4: 1;
  // ...
} flags = {};


initializers only work in C++20 and I don't have that.

I don't need any specific alignment so the third version looks good. Thanks!

@ChiftiSaidi What is uint16_t: 0; supposed to be for if not to force the alignment to 2?

It was to make it into a known size for my typecast.

@ChiftiSaidi But it doesn't actually guarantee to do that as I explained.

If you want to do type-punning, it's better-defined to do it with a union, instead of via brute-force pointer-casting.  Like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union packed_bits_union
{
   struct packed_bits
   {
      bool b1 : 1;
      bool b2 : 2;
      bool b3 : 3;
      bool b4 : 4;
   } individualBits;

   uint16_t allBits;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   packed_bits_union pbu;
   pbu.allBits = 0;
   pbu.individualBits.b1 = true;

   printf("sizeof(pbu)=%zu\n", sizeof(pbu));  // prints "sizeof(pbu)=2"
   return 0;
}


Untagged unions in C++ are an UB minefield, and type punning with unions in C++  is not safe (read : Is it allowed to use unions for type punning, and if not, why?) . So they must be handled with care too.  If one wants control of individual bits just use bitmasks.
